# iOS Facebook SDK permissions without review

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

In my app, I use `FBLoginView` with `user_events`, `user_groups` and some other permissions. Here what we can read on developers.facebook.com:

> If your app asks for more than than public_profile, email and user_friends it will require review by Facebook before your app can be used by people other than the app's developers.
>
> The time to review your app is usually about 7 business days. Some
>   extra-sensitive permissions, as noted below, can take up to 14
>   business days.

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0)

But if my app logics is based on Facebook SDK and its permissions unavailable whitout review, how can I prepare the app for the review? Is there any test mode with all permissions granted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Admins, developers and testers of the app you can ask to permit any permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the possibility to test the reviewed permissions using a test user account.

Select the app you are working on in the `Apps`. In your left-hand menu open `Roles` tab, there you can select `Test Users` and use test email and password to login on Facebook for working with closed permissions.

[image]

UPD: In the `Roles` tab you can add your account to `Administrators`, `Developers` or `Testers` to get access to the permissions.